# invalid factor level, NA generated for only one level in a factor variable

Tags: r, na, levels

I have looked through other answers for this eror code and they do bnot resolve my problem.

I am trying to change the level of one variable based on the level of another variable.

I am able to do this for two levels of the variable, but not the third, which is when I get the error message:

Warning message:
In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, supportdf$Q7a == "I did not need any additional support",  :
invalid factor level, NA generated

It is hard to replicate the error as I can't share the data set, but this is the closest approximation

```
var1<- c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "Yes, from my family", "Yes, from my family", NA, "Yes, from my family" )
var2<- c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "Yes, from my friends", NA, NA, "Yes, from my friends", "Yes, from my friends" )
var3<- c("I did not need any additional support", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "I did not need any additional support", NA, NA )
var4<- c(NA, "I did not need any additional support", "Yes, from my family", "Yes, from my friends", "I did not need any additional support", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA )
df<- data.frame(var1, var2, var3, var4)
df

   var1                 var2                                  var3                                  var4
1                 <NA>                 <NA> I did not need any additional support                                  <NA>
2                 <NA>                 <NA>                                  <NA> I did not need any additional support
3                 <NA>                 <NA>                                  <NA>                   Yes, from my family
4                 <NA>                 <NA>                                  <NA>                  Yes, from my friends
5                 <NA>                 <NA>                                  <NA> I did not need any additional support
6                 <NA> Yes, from my friends                                  <NA>                                  <NA>
7  Yes, from my family                 <NA>                                  <NA>                                  <NA>
8  Yes, from my family                 <NA> I did not need any additional support                                  <NA>
9                 <NA> Yes, from my friends                                  <NA>                                  <NA>
10 Yes, from my family Yes, from my friends                                  <NA>                                  <NA>
```

Ultimately I want to change var1, var2 and var3 based on the var4 value and then change var4 to NA as below

```
var1a<- c(NA, NA,  "Yes, from my family", NA, NA, NA, "Yes, from my family", "Yes, from my family", NA, "Yes, from my family" )
var2a<- c(NA, NA, NA, "Yes, from my friends", NA, "Yes, from my friends", NA, NA, "Yes, from my friends", "Yes, from my friends" )
var3a<- c("I did not need any additional support", "I did not need any additional support", NA, NA, "I did not need any additional support", NA, NA, "I did not need any additional support", NA, NA )
var4a<- c(NA, NA,NA, NA , NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA )
dfa<- data.frame(var1a, var2a, var3a, var4a)
dfa
                 var1a                var2a                                 var3a var4a
1                 <NA>                 <NA> I did not need any additional support    NA
2                 <NA>                 <NA> I did not need any additional support    NA
3  Yes, from my family                 <NA>                                  <NA>    NA
4                 <NA> Yes, from my friends                                  <NA>    NA
5                 <NA>                 <NA> I did not need any additional support    NA
6                 <NA> Yes, from my friends                                  <NA>    NA
7  Yes, from my family                 <NA>                                  <NA>    NA
8  Yes, from my family                 <NA> I did not need any additional support    NA
9                 <NA> Yes, from my friends                                  <NA>    NA
10 Yes, from my family Yes, from my friends                                  <NA>    NA
```

I've been doing it like this

```
df$var1[df$var4 == "Yes, from my family" ]<- "Yes, from my family" 
df$var4[df$var4 == "Yes, from my family" ]<- NA

df$var2[df$var4== "Yes, from my friends" ]<- "Yes, from my friends"
df$var4[df$var4 == "Yes, from my friends" ]<- NA
```

but when I get to var3 (in my dataset, not in a made up example) I get the error message

```
df$var3[df$var4 == "I did not need any additional support" ]<- "I did not need any additional support"
Warning message:
  In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, supportdf$Q7a == "I did not need any additional support",  :
                    #invalid factor level, NA generated
```

Why would this be the case only for this level? I've also tried with an if clause but that doesn't work and I get this error message

```
df<- if (df$var4 == "I did not need any additional support")df$Qvar3<-"I did not need any additional support"
Error in if (supportdf$Q7a == "I did not need any additional support") supportdf$Q7.6 <- "I did not need any additional support" : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
In addition: Warning message:
In if (supportdf$Q7a == "I did not need any additional support") supportdf$Q7.6 <- "I did not need any additional support" :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

Any help or advice appreciated

Comment: Turn the values to characters. You could do `df<- data.frame(var1, var2, var3, var4, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)` Or if the dataframe is already created `df[] <- lapply(df, as.character)`

Comment: If I understand the problem right, why don't you create new columns to consolidate the results like: `df$var5 = ifelse((var1 == "Yes, from my family" | var2 == "Yes, from my family" | var3 == "Yes, from my family" | var4 == "Yes, from my family"), "Yes, from my family", "")
df$var6 = ifelse((var1 == "Yes, from my friends" | var2 == "Yes, from my friends" | var3 == "Yes, from my friends" | var4 == "Yes, from my friends"), "Yes, from my friends", "")`

Comment: `df$var7 = ifelse((var1 == "I did not need any additional support" | var2 == "I did not need any additional support" | var3 == "I did not need any additional support" | var4 == "I did not need any additional support"), "I did not need any additional support", "")`